# How to mock an IIFE while importing in jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am quite confused on how to mock an IIFE while importing it in my jest file.
I have a JS file which contains multiple functions which I want to test except that IIFE. While importing the JS file in my test throws an error due to the document object used inside IIFE.

I don't want to test that IIFE function. Is there any way to avoid such case in jest.

I tried to mock document using setupFiles (in jest config) but no luck.

Also tried the below code in my test file to mock it ,but no luck again.

```
jest.mock('./myModule.js', () => (
  {
    ...(jest.requireActual('./myModule.js')),
    otherFn: () => {}
  }
));
```

I am beginner in jest and just want to avoid testing that IIFE.

Is there any way to avoid execution of an IIFE while import or to mock it?

Answer (score 1):

An IIFE will always run when the file gets imported.

You can mock the entire file so it never runs, but then you can't access the functions defined in it.

There isn't a way to mock just the IIFE while still being able to access the other functions defined in the same file since anything that imports the code (including `jest.requireActual`) will also run the IIFE.

Sounds like the two options you have are to set up your testing environment so that the IIFE doesn't throw an error when it runs, or move the functions to their own module so you can import and test them independently from the IIFE.

Comment: Thanks for the information @brian-lives-outdoors...
My IIFE executes <document.querySelector('meta[name="_csrf"]').content> and throws error "cannot read property 'content' of null"

Is there any way to mock it while importing?

Answer (score 0):

add a wrapper

```js
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        factory()();
    }
}(function() {
    // you code
    return function () {}
        
}));
```